# Kibana - Watcher when a server goes down and a followup if it’s been down for 24 hours?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, heartbeat, metricbeat

I have a number of servers being pinged by heartbeat. What I'm trying to figure out how to do is:

"Watcher 1" run every minute - When a server has been consistently down for a minute (no monitor.status = up for any documents for one particular address in heartbeat for the past 60 seconds of documents), send an email notification, then trigger a "watcher" to evaluate again every 24 hours.

- "Watcher 2" - At the 24 hour mark, if the server has still been consistently down (no monitor.status = up for any document for that one address pinged in any of the heartbeat documents returned for that server for the past 24 hours), trigger another email.
- During this "wait 24 hour" period, suspend "Watcher 1" running every minute on the server

Is something like this doable with the watcher/alerting functionality (without customization)? I've seen workflows posted before about a 
simple downtime notification, but not sure if the rest of this can be performed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking at [Throttling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/actions.html#actions-ack-throttle) option in watchers. As per the Elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/actions.html#actions-ack-throttle)

> During the watch execution, once the condition is met, a decision is
>   made per configured action as to whether it should be throttled. The
>   main purpose of action throttling is to prevent too many executions of
>   the same action for the same watch.

```
"actions" : {
    "email_administrator" : {
      "throttle_period": "24h", 
      "email" : { 
        "to" : "sys.admino@host.domain",
        "subject" : "Encountered {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} errors",
        "body" : "Too many error in the system, see attached data",
        "attachments" : {
          "attached_data" : {
            "data" : {
              "format" : "json"
            }
          }
        },
        "priority" : "high"
      }
    }
```